# Swap image on mouseover inside fancybox gallery?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, fancybox, mouseover

When a thumbnail is clicked and the image loads into the Fancybox slideshow, I would like to then be able to toggle between two different versions of the image when hovering over it.

I've been trying various pieces of code that I've found through searching the questions on here, though I can't found a Q&A with my exact problem.

I've tried various different versions of the mouseover script, like the below:

```
$("#test").mouseover(function (e) {    
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("images/rt/test1.jpg", "images/rt/test2.jpg"));
}).mouseout(function (e) {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("images/rt/test2.jpg", "images/rt/test1.jpg"));
});
```

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/rt/test1.jpg" data-caption="lorem ipsum" id="test">
    <img src="images/rt/thumb.jpg" height="85px" width="85px">
</a>
```

This is the piece of code which loads the image into the slideshow:

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="images/rt/test1.jpg" data-caption="lorem ipsum">
    <img src="images/rt/thumb.jpg" height="85px" width="85px">
</a>
```

The img src part is the thumbnail, but what I need to toggle versions on is the image referenced by the href tag. I've not been able to find anything yet that will do this.

The one thing I've found which does actually work is the below, but it only works when I use it with the img tag, not when I try to apply it to the href part.

```
<img src="images/rt/test1.jpg" height="85px" width="85px" onmouseover="this.src='images/rt/test2.jpg'"onmouseout="this.src='images/rt/test1.jpg'">
```

Ideally I need something like this that I can put into the href tag, OR some amendment to the mouseout function which can target the right part of fancybox.

If you couldn't tell, I'm a real beginner with jquery so I might be missing something really obvious!

Comment: So, you want to change `href` attribute on mouse over event? Why on earth would you want to do that? And why do you think your first snipped would not work, please, provide live demo on codepen/jsfiddel/whatever

Comment: I don't want to change an URL, it's the image which is loaded that I want to manipulate on mouse over. But the way that the gallery seems to work is that the image which loads up and becomes full-size is referenced by the image url in that set of 'a' tags. Which doesn't appear to respond the same way that the 'img' tags do e.g. when I try to introduce a class/id. Can't get my head around it. 
Have tried to bung it all in to codepen - https://codepen.io/owlyone/pen/dybmbzK

So it's the image that loads once you click the thumb which is what I want to be able to change on hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is the same as to 99% of the other questions related to fancybox - simply use callbacks. Callbacks allow you to execute your code at various stages of progress, for example, right after image is loaded. So, the code could be something like this:

```
$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
  afterLoad : function(instance, current) {

    current.$image.mouseover(function (e) {    
      $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("/id/1", "/id/2"));
    }).mouseout(function (e) {
      $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("/id/2", "/id/1"));
    });

  }
});
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/1t5wpzqc/